# Does `ps` command on MacOS have permission for non-admin user?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I am creating an app using the following command to get CPU and memory usage:

```
ps -A -o %cpu,%mem | awk '{ cpu += $1; mem += $2} END {print cpu , mem}'
```

I wonder whether all users have permission to run it and get the same results? If there is an admin process, whether the `ps` command outputs it for a guest user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ps -A` shows all processes, regardless of user. From the man page:

> -A Display information about other users' processes, including those without controlling terminals.

Answer (score 0):

`ps` has the setuid bit set in which the process runs with the permissions of the owner, `root` for any user that invokes the command.